# Setar valores de um array recursivamente

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, set

Supondo que eu tenha o seguinte array

```
array(
'chave1' => 'valor1',
'chave2' => array(
    'chave3' => 'valor2',
    'chave4' => array(
        'chave5' => 'valor3'
    )
))
```

E neste array eu precise setar o valor da chave 5, mas sem precisar ir nível por nível, poderia passar para uma função dessa forma :

```
setar_valor('chave2.chave4.chave5', 'meu novo valor');
```

E esta função iria interpretar que cada `.` seria um novo nível dentro do array.

Já quebrei a cabeça com isso, mas não consigo pensar em como fazer :/

Comment: O cakephp se organiza exatamente dessa forma, vou ver como eles fazer isso, vou procurar na documentação

Comment: É necessário mesmo interpretar `chave2.chave4.chave5` dividindo cada nível pelo `.`? não seria mais fácil percorrer toda a *array* e alterar o valor de acordo com a chave?

Comment: @qmechanik seria mais fácil sim, porem iria ter conflito se tiver mais de uma chave 5 em níveis diferentes do array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer uma função que vai "mergulhando" por referência nessa array, seguindo as chaves (níveis de profundidade) extraídas dessa string com `$niveis = explode('.', $path);`

Usando `&` podes passar por referência arrays, portanto quando tens `$foo = $array[$key];` mudando `$foo` estás a mudar o valor de `$array[$key]`.

```
function setar_valor($path, $str, &$array){
    $niveis = explode('.', $path);
    $temp = &$array;
    foreach ( $niveis as $key ) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $str;
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/H6D3Og

O código completo:

```
$arr = array(
'chave1' => 'valor1',
'chave2' => array(
    'chave3' => 'valor2',
    'chave4' => array(
        'chave5' => 'valor3'
    )
));

function setar_valor($path, $str, &$array){
    $niveis = explode('.', $path);
    $temp = &$array;
    foreach ( $niveis as $key ) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $str;
}

setar_valor('chave2.chave4.chave5', 'meu novo valor', $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  ["chave1"]=>
  string(6) "valor1"
  ["chave2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["chave3"]=>
    string(6) "valor2"
    ["chave4"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["chave5"]=>
      string(14) "meu novo valor"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: valeu pela ajuda cara, valeu mesmo